# Equivalence relation of legendre symbols

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question states that p is a prime of the form $4k+1$. Using this prove the follwowing: $$\left(\frac ap\right)=\left(\frac qp\right)$$ where $q=p-a$. I tried to simply replace $p$ but that doesn't make much sense. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The claim is equivalent to $\left({-1\over p}\right)=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how so?

Comment: @Paradox101 because the Legendre symbol is multiplicative.

Comment: @Callus that's true but how does that relate to the question above? How do I find the legendre symbol for the one on the right side?

Comment: @Paradox101 one more hint: if $a \equiv b \pmod p$ then $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right) = \left( \frac{b}{p} \right)$

Comment: @Callus what you're saying is that $p-a$ is congruent to $a$ mod $p$ which is why they are equivalent? But then, how will the form $4k+1$ be used in the question?

Comment: @Paradox101 No,  $p-a \equiv -a \pmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ has order $4k$. So if $\epsilon$ is a generator, we have $-1\equiv \epsilon^r\pmod p$ for some integer $r$ and from $1\equiv \epsilon^{2r}\pmod p$ we conclude that $4k\mid 2r$, i.e. $r$ is even. Then $-1\equiv (\epsilon^{r/2})^2\pmod p$, i.e. $\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=+1$. Then from $q\equiv (-1)\cdot a\pmod p$ we get $$\left(\frac{q}p\right)=\left(\frac{-1}p\right)\left(\frac{a}p\right)=\left(\frac{a}p\right).$$

Comment: can you please give a simpler explanation? I don't know anything about cyclic groups yet. Thanks